How to Properly Store and Use a PEM File for SSH in GitHub Actions?

I'm trying to use GitHub Actions to deploy code to an EC2 instance. I've added my PEM file (the private key used for SSH) as a secret in GitHub, but I'm encountering the following error during the deployment:
Load key "web-server.pem": error in libcrypto
Permission denied (publickey).
I've followed these steps:
Copied the entire content of my .pem file (including -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----) and added it as a GitHub secret.
Referenced the secret in my GitHub Actions workflow to SSH into the EC2 instance.
Here’s a snippet of my GitHub Actions workflow:
name: Deploy to EC2
env:
  SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY }}
  EC2_HOST: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
  EC2_USER: ubuntu  
run: |
  echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > web-server.pem
  chmod 600 web-server.pem
  ssh -i web-server.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.EC2_USER }}@${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}

Despite following these steps, I'm still facing issues. Could someone provide guidance on the correct way to store and use a PEM file in GitHub Actions, or suggest what might be causing the "Permission denied (publickey)" error?

The step syntax looks fine. Based on your description, the key is fine as well.
Try logging in with that key from your local machine. The reason it is not accepted is most likely the wrong user. The error is saying that the user on the host does not have a matching public key.
